# Is it possible to query the lookup object fields of child object?How to do it?

Tags: query, master-detail

We have a parent object say **ParentA** with its associated child object as **ChildA** with a custom field **customerName** of type lookup(**Account**). Now I would like to retrieve **AccountNumber**, which is field on Account, that is referred by **customerName** field.

```
ParentA Bp= [select Name__c, 
             (select customerName__r.AccountNumber from ChildA__r)
             from ParentA
            ];
```

Once queried how can I call it? Should it be like a **Bp.ChildA__r.Customer__r.AccountNumber**? If I use it I am getting next:

```
Compile Error: Invalid foreign key relationship?Any suggestion?
```

Comment: if you need from child - [SELECT customerName.AccountNumber FROM ChildA]
if from parent - [SELECT Id, [SELECT customerName.Accountnumber, Id FROM ChildARelationShip] FROM ParentA].

Comment: Thanks but I have edited the question again?can you please help me with that?

Comment: idea is that in parent - child relationship you have queried not single record, but multiple.  So to get it you need to type Bp.ChildA__r.get(0).Customer__r.AccountNumber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a *one-to-many* relationship. That means, that *one* parent can have *multiple* children. Using a subquery you will get (theoretically) multiple child records. It is a list. So you should access this portion of records using a list syntax:

```
ParentA Bp = [select Name__c, 
             (select customerName__r.AccountNumber from ChildA__r)
              from ParentA];

ChildA__c child1 = Bp.ChildA__r[0];
...
ChildA__c childN = Bp.ChildA__r[N];
```

You can learn more about accessing relationships here: [Traversing and Querying sObject Relationships](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex6_3.htm)

One example from that document:

> This second example demonstrates the retrieval of child sObjects. It
>   retrieves child line items of an invoice statement using the nested
>   query (SELECT Value__c FROM Line_Items__r). It then obtains the child
>   line items of the invoice statement through the returned invoice
>   statement sObject.

```
Invoice_Statement__c inv = [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Units_Sold__c FROM Line_Items__r)
                            FROM Invoice_Statement__c
                            WHERE Name='INV-0000'];
// Access child records.
List<Line_Item__c> lis = inv.Line_Items__r;
System.debug('Number of child line items: ' + lis.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is the sub query

```
[...,(select customerName__r.AccountNumber from ChildA__r)...]
```

because you are use a the object api name, and you need use th child relationship name(you can see the name in the field).

**Example:**

```
[SELECT id,Name,(SELECT Id,FirstName,LastName FROM **Contacts**) FROM Account]
```

In this case we are using Contacts instead of Contact.